# Compounding Yearly Interest and Taking Out Money on a Yearly Basis

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program where someone has $2,000,000 in their bank account and they earn 7% on it each year. However, each year this person takes out $200,000 and I want to find out how many years it would take for the account to be emptied out. I am using `dollars * pow((1+rate), years)` to calculate how much money is in the bank each year with the interest he is gaining on it. Afterwards, I am subtracting `200000 * years` from that in order to get the total amount in the bank after a certain number of years. I am required to use a `while loop` so please keep that in mind. I set the it so that `while (total > 0)` that way the loop would stop when the account reaches $0. But for some reason my code is not running. I would appreciate it if someone could help me fix it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
    float dollars = 2000000;
    float rate = 0.07;
    float years = 0;
    float ci, total;

    while (total > 0){
            years++;
        ci = dollars * pow((1+rate), years);
        total = ci - (200000 * years);
    }
    printf("It takes %f years for Frank to empty his account.", years);
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `total` is never set before you use it the first time. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: Your computation doesn't make sense.  At each year, the new value is `dollars = dollars * ( 1 + rate ) - 200000`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's correct. But it is going to take more than one year for the account to be emptied out hence why I multiply times the numbers of years in ``(200000 * years)``.

Comment: @John3136 What should I set it equal to? If I set it equal to 0 to start with, the code will run but the output does not come out as I want it to.

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to use `pow`.  That's what the loop is doing.  `pow` just incorporates the loop in the calculation.  (eg, you use `pow` instead of a loop, you don't use both)

Comment: @Rivf Sometimes it helps to do the calculation with pencil and paper, before you go writing code. If you don't know how to do the calculations yourself, you won't be able to teach a computer to do the calculations. So ask yourself, what is the interest for the first year? What is the account balance at the end of the first year? And what is the interest for the second year? Hint: the answer to that third question is **not** 140000.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Aaaah ok, I did not know that. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @user3386109 I know how to do it on paper, I just wasn't sure why my code wasn't running properly. I know how to get the answer to all your questions but I am not confident in my skills to translate that into the code.

Comment: @Rivf Then the next step is to learn how to debug your program. The simple way is to add printfs to the code. For example, at the top of the loop you could print `years`, `dollars`, `ci`, and `total`. Then compare those values with the numbers that you get by hand to see if they match.

Comment: @user3386109 I am an idiot. I just realized what was fundamentally wrong with my calculation. Thank you for both for bearing with me and helping me out.

Comment: @Rivf It always hardest at the beginning of learning something new. Best of luck to you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculation is incorrect.  Just do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
        float dollars = 2000000.0;
        float rate = 0.07;
        int years = 0;

        while( dollars > 0.0 ) {
                years += 1;
                dollars = dollars * (1 + rate) - 200000;
        }
        printf("It takes %d years for Frank to empty his account.\n", years);

        return 0;
}
```

But you might want to put some logic in to check if the balance is increasing at each year, and parameterize the values.  For example:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        float dollars = argc > 1 ? strtod(argv[1], NULL) : 2000000;
        float prev = dollars;
        float rate = argc > 2 ? strtod(argv[2], NULL) : 0.07;
        int years = 0;

        while( dollars > 0 ) {
                years += 1;
                dollars = dollars * (1 + rate) - 200000;
                if( dollars >= prev ) {
                        printf("Balance is increasing\n");
                        return 1;
                }
        }
        printf("It takes %d years for Frank to empty his account.\n", years);

        return 0;
}
```